# Ruby Telegram bot message is not modified error if two inline button is clicked at once

Tags: ruby, mongodb, telegram

I have a Telegram bot which utilizes inline keyboard to get user's input. Because it queries a DB, it often takes a while for the next message to come through.

The first message displays a set of inline options. Once clicked, this message is modified and a second inline keyboard is displayed. However, if users were to click the first inline message buttons rapidly, I get the following error:

`Telegram API has returned the error. (ok: "false", error_code: "400", description: "Bad Request: message is not modified") (Telegram::Bot::Exceptions::ResponseError)`

I suspect this has to do with the fact that by editing the message, the API needs to know the message ID it has to edit - which is invalidated by the second inline query. As such this error is thrown as the API does not know which message to edit.

Is there a way to mitigate this? Maybe by removing the inline keyboard as soon as any button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have 3 options:

1. Ignore this type of error
2. Append different string (e.g., `Last updated time`)
3. Log which message has been updated to your own database